# Get ids of dynamically generated checkboxes that were selected

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Suppose I have x checkboxes:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="ams" value="False">
<input type="checkbox" id="lon" value="False">
<input type="checkbox" id="ber" value="False">
<input type="checkbox" id="par" value="False">
```

And I'd like upon pressing a button:

```
<button type="submit_cities" id="submit_cities">Print selected cities</button>
```

To print the IDs of the checkboxes that were selected.
Is there a way to go about it?
Thanks!

Comment: You should at least _try_ a search before asking a question.....  Use the 'Search' box at the top of the page and enter 'checkbox checked' (no quotes) - you'll get about 95,000 answers.......

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a clickhandler using the id of the button and then loop though the selected inputs:

```js
$("#submit_cities").click(function() {
  $('input:checked').each((_, elm) => console.log(elm.id));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" id="ams" value="False">
<input type="checkbox" id="lon" value="False">
<input type="checkbox" id="ber" value="False">
<input type="checkbox" id="par" value="False">
<button type="submit_cities" id="submit_cities">Print selected cities</button>
```

Comment: Thanks, I went with this in the end, due to simplicity

Answer (score 2):

Check out my solution below.

```js
const checkboxes = [ ...document.querySelectorAll('input[type="checkbox"]') ]
const submitButton = document.querySelector('#submit_cities')

const getCheckedIDs = () => 
  checkboxes
    .filter(checkbox => checkbox.checked)
    .map(checkbox => checkbox.getAttribute('id'))

submitButton.onclick = () => {
  console.log(getCheckedIDs())
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" id="ams" value="False">
<input type="checkbox" id="lon" value="False">
<input type="checkbox" id="ber" value="False">
<input type="checkbox" id="par" value="False">
<button type="submit_cities" id="submit_cities">Print selected cities</button>
```

Answer (score 2):

Invalid type of button .so change with `type="button"`.You could use [`Jquery#filter`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) , [`Jquery#map`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.map/) and [`.get()`](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/) api

And Use [`.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/)  specially for a  dynamically appended element

```js
$(document).on('click', '#submit_cities', function() {
  var $arr = $('input[type="checkbox"]').filter((a, b) => $(b).is(':checked')).map((a, b) => $(b).attr('id')).get()
  console.log($arr)
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" id="ams" value="False">
<input type="checkbox" id="lon" value="False">
<input type="checkbox" id="ber" value="False">
<input type="checkbox" id="par" value="False"> And I'd like upon pressing a button:

<button type="button" id="submit_cities">Print selected cities</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution:

```js
function select()
{
   var results=$("input:checkbox:checked");
   for (i=0;i< results.length;i++)
   {
     alert(results[i].id);
   }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" id="ams" value="False">
<input type="checkbox" id="lon" value="False">
<input type="checkbox" id="ber" value="False">
<input type="checkbox" id="par" value="False">

<button onclick="select()">
Go
</button>
```